# Linux kernel Kconfig: How do I de-select an option?

Tags: linux-kernel

How do I de-select an option?
For example, the following script is what I want to achieve:

```
choice                                                                                         
    prompt "Camera type"                                                                       
    default CAMERA1                                                                            

config CAMERA1                                                                                 
    select POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH                                                               

config CAMERA2                                                                                 
    deselect POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH

config CAMERA3                                                                                 
    select POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH                                                         

endchoice                                                                                      

config POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH                                                                   
    bool "Power pin is high active?"                                                           
    help  Say 'y' if the power pin is high active, 'n' if low active.
```

Apparently, there is no `de-select` command, or even `select XXXX = n` command.

How do I achieve the effect, or other ways to achieve the script's goal?
In addition, I want to hide the `POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH` option.  It should be automatically selected/deselected when a type of camera is selected.

**--Update--**

I tried it in a different way.  It's working but `Makefile` gives me a force select of `POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH` warning:

```
choice                                                                                         
    prompt "Camera type"                                                                       
    default CAMERA1                                                                            

config CAMERA1                                                                                 
    select POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH                                                               

config CAMERA2                                                                                 
    deselect POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH

config CAMERA3                                                                                 
    select POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH                                                         

endchoice                                                                                      

config POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH
    depends on __HIDDEN_OPTION__                                                                   
    bool "Power pin is high active?"                                                           
    help  Say 'y' if the power pin is high active, 'n' if low active.
```

The script works since `__HIDDEN_OPTION__` is never a configuration option, and thus it cause the dependency failed for all cases.  Only those forceful `select` command can override it and select the configuration.  Though `Makefile` gives an warning, due to the not-matched (never-matched) `__HIDDEN_OPTION__` condition.

Any better idea?

Comment: Deselecting is a bad thing (user point of view): you override a selection of the user without notifying. [Distribution handle package dependencies better, but kernel configuration is not for everyone). You should go on the other way: you can select only if the other is unselected (and add in the help the reason). So it would be obvious the intent.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got my own answer:

```
choice
    prompt "Camera type"
    default CAMERA1

config CAMERA1
    bool "camera1 support"
    select POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH

config CAMERA2
    bool "camera2 support"

config CAMERA3
    bool "camera3 support"
    select POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH

config CAMERA4
    bool "camera4 support"

endchoice

config POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH
    depends on CAMERA1 || CAMERA3
    # or, alternatively, we can say depends on !CAMERA2 && !CAMERA4

    # Since this shows up only when CAMERA1 || CAMERA2, we don't need help,
    # and we don't ask question, just an affirmative statement.
    bool "This camera has an active-high power pin."
```

Yet this answer the Kconfig writer has to  be careful to keep things consistent. Another disadvantage is, it does not show "active-low" when one of those active-low power pin cameras is selected.

I will accept this answer in a few days, if no better answer is proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Default and select can be used to achieve the same

```
config POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH
    bool
    default n

config CAMERA1                                                                                 
    select POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH

config CAMERA2
```

Comment: But that means, for `CAMERA2`, the user can still select `POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH`.

Comment: CAMERA2 itself can be disabled if it has such dependency. It should mention in its -               "select !POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH"

Comment: Got an syntax error when using `select !POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH`.  It seems the negate mark (!) could be used only in conditions like `depends on` command.

Comment: @RobinHsu The user can't select `POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH` manually because it has no prompt.

Comment: I think the `default n` can be omitted as that's the default default.

Comment: @ Ian Abbott:  Thanks.  You are right.  Prompt is the problem!   I should omit the description in quotes (i.e. the prompt) in  `POWER_PIN_ACTIVE_HIGH` config. Could you post it as an answer?